# checking session data using id, and changing id within a loop

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm doing a little server-side project, where I need to check if a session variable is set, using session id's that are stored in my database.

The problem I'm getting, is that I don't want to destroy the session after I've checked if the variable is set. So I need a way to either check the variable without having to start the session, or find a way to change to a different session id while the session is started,
or duplicate the session to a different session that I can destroy.

Here's what I have:

```
while(true) {
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT sessionid FROM sessions");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
        session_id($row['sessionid']);
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['value'])) {
            $stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sessionid=:sessionid");
            $stmt->bindValue(':sessionid',$row['sessionid'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        session_destroy();
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done it Lol ...

```
while(true) {
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT sessionid FROM sessions");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
        session_id($row['sessionid']);
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(false);
        $newsessionid=session_id();
        session_write_close();
        session_id($newsessionid);
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['value'])) {
            $stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sessionid=:sessionid");
            $stmt->bindValue(':sessionid',$row['sessionid'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        session_destroy();
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php